# How to make the content of your fragment tabhost occupy full width?

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-tab-host

I have placed `ImageView`, fragment tabhost and an `ImageButton` on a bar I created, I want the content of the tabhost to occupy the full width however all I am getting is as shown in the image. I searched high and low but couldn't find a solution!

The XML code is as below

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2D5990"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.105"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" /> 

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="No Desc"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:gravity="right" 
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />     
 </LinearLayout>
```

Sorry I have updated the code now

[Awkward view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOZ5P.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the fragment tabhost wont occupy full width if you are using `ImageView` and `ImageButton` inside your layout.

You have to use only `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost`, if you want your fragment tabhost to occupy full width of your layout.

So, try removing `ImageView` and `ImageButton` from your layout.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
Got the answer after a long time !